# Difference between "noto" and "conosciuto"

Tags: word-meaning, difference, synonym

Is there any difference in meaning between "noto" and "conosciuto" ? If I got it right, the former is more usual. Example:

- È un cantante noto.
- È un cantante conosciuto.

Comment: If it can be useful to someone writing an answer: here is what Tommaseo wrote in his _Dizionario dei sinonimi_: https://imgur.com/ITTWx0h

Comment: They are similar, they both means "known" but noto is more like "famous"

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Lorenzo! Potresti dare un po' più di dettagli? (magari usando come fonte il link al *Dizionario dei sinonimi*  di Tommaseo che ha messo DaG nel suo commento).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, they are almost the same, both in meaning and usage.
But some differences exist; if you use those adjectives before the noun:

- E' un noto cantante/politico
- E' un conosciuto cantante/politico

The first phrase is more common, albeit the second is not erroneous.

Another example, taken from another answer, is:

- Come è noto, ...

This is more common than "Come è conosciuto, ...". Probably this is because "noto" implies a general acceptance of the knowledge, a little like "notorious" in English , while "conosciuto" is slightly more dull in that sense.

Another difference is that in *conosciuto* the past participle is easily felt, while *noto* is purely an adjective; so it is more easy to construct phrases like: *mi è nota la sua tenacia* (Treccani: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/noto/), while the same utterance with *conosciuta* would sound slightly different; in some cases such kind of construction can be erroneous (or felt as such because the presence of a participle).

Answer (score 0):

Le differenze sono piuttosto sottili, entrambi sono aggettivi ed entrambi sono intercambiabili, ma:

## [conosciuto](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/conosciuto)

> **1. che si conosce**
>
> e.g. "Fra gli effetti collaterali **conosciuti** di questa sostanza ci sono delle forti allucinazioni."
>   *(=Strong hallucinations are among the known side effects of this substance.)*
>
> **2. noto, famoso**
>
> e.g. "Lo zio di una mia compagna di classe è un politico molto **conosciuto**."
>   *(=The uncle of one of my classmates is a very famous (or: well-known) politician.)*

**N.B.** In entrambi questi due esempi avrei potuto sostituire **"conosciuto"** con **"noto"** aggiungendo un pizzico di formalità in più.

## [noto](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/noto)

> **1. fatto risaputo** *(formale)*
>
> e.g. "Come è **noto**, bere molta acqua fa bene." 
>   *(=As is generally known drinking a lot of water is good for you.)*
>
> **2. noto, famoso** *(formale)*
>
> e.g. "È un personaggio piuttosto **noto** da queste parti." 
>   *(=He's a fairly well-known person in this area.)*

**N.B.** Nel primo esempio non avrei potuto sostituire **"noto"** con **"conosciuto"**, poiché **"conosciuto"** in quel contesto non è l'aggettivo adeguato. Nel secondo esempio avrei invece potuto sostituire **"noto"** con **"conosciuto"**, ma ciò avrebbe reso la frase più colloquiale e meno formale.

Comment: Perché "conosciuto" sarebbe stato non grammaticalmente corretto nel primo esempio de "noto" ?

Comment: @ilMagnifico:  Non credo si tratti di un problema grammaticale, ma di significato: "conosciuto" non si usa come aggettivo per qualificare un fatto risaputo, vero?

Comment: Ragazzi, semplicemente non si usa "conosciuto" in quella frase, non si dice, è sgrammaticato e sbagliato. In quel contesto se proprio non si vuole utilizzare "noto" si può sostituire con "risaputo" che equivarrebbe allo stesso sia in significato che formalità; anche se "È risaputo che bere molta acqua fa bene" è più comune. Saluti.

Comment: Cosa? Downvote?? La risposta è corretta ragazzi, sono Italiano, saprò la differenza?? Mha

Comment: @ilMagnifico veramente si scrive "Mah".

Comment: Confermo quanto detto da altri: la grammatica non c'entra. Dire “il sole è viola” non è un errore grammaticale: è solo che “viola” non è un aggettivo appropriato per “sole”.

Comment: Okay, allora editate il messaggio e modificare quella parte. il restante 99% del messaggio è corretto. Non capisco quei downvote così a caso quando il messaggio eccetto quella frase è corretto. E' oltretutto citato da una fonte. Saluti

Comment: Ciao @Nico, grazie.

Comment: @ilMagnifico buoni esempi in parte giusti, puoi modificare tu stesso la risposta in modo che sia al 100% corretta